# ASP.NET Core API Time gets 6 Hours off from Angular post call

Tags: angular, timezone, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to send a datetime from angular app to the ASP.NET Core web API via post call, but after sending the correct date the API receives a time that is 6 hours behind than the time has sent.

```
this.subject.StartTime = form.value.startTime ? moment(today + ' ' + form.value.startTime) : '';
this.subject.EndTime = form.value.endTime ? moment(today + ' ' + form.value.endTime).toDate() : '';
```

Angular sent's  `Wed Sep 25 2019 22:00:00 GMT+0600`

ASP.NET Core receives
[image]

Why it's happening, do I have to set my culture in my ASP.NET Core app? but my client and server in same timezone.
Is there any way to set my default Timezone in the asp.net core? as we set `DefaultRequestCulture`.

Comment: It is because of the conversion between datetime and datetimeoffset it took off the +6 hrs from GMT time. Its not wrong just 2 different ways of looking at time.

Comment: @DanGorman how to get the same time that was sent from client?

Comment: It is the same time just represented as UTC. Is the date a datetimeoffset on your backend?

Comment: no the date is okay. jfyi when server return the time to the client it returns the wrong time as well.

Comment: My question was is the value for the date and time being save as a datetime or a datetimeoffset in your ASP.NET app/database? It is converting the time to UTC, it is not wrong. It just is not converting it out of UTC back to your timezone in the response to the client. A way to get around that is not convert it to UTC and save the value as a dattimeoffset.

Comment: thank you, will have a look.

Comment: Note that in the code shown here, the first line you are assigning a raw `moment` object, and the second line you are assigning a `Date` object.  You probably should be doing the same thing in both cases, and you probably should be using moment's `format` function.  It's hard to tell what you're doing here exactly though, as you haven't provided a [complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  You should show specific example values of the inputs, and you should show your back-end code as well.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint That was intentional, to show that anyway sending the date become the UTC in backend but angular not converting the time to local time . What I'm doing?? I'm taking time as input and making a full datetime object to save in the db. Thank you.

Comment: When you retrieve the time from the database (in UTC) try setting it to a new Date object, then use the DatePipe to adjust the formatting. `this.localTime = new Date(this.utcTime)` in the html `{{localTime | date:'long'}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Date from the server is a UTC Date, so I had to convert the date object to a local DateTime object in the front-end like below.

```
var date = new Date(dateString).toString() + 'Z';
```

in some places I saw only using `new Date(dateString)` works fine but in my case, I had to add `+'Z'` at end of dateString, It's a UTC Date String.